# Mandatory to implement HTTPOnly if Java Secure Cookies are set to 'true'?

Tags: xss, http, cookies, audit, csrf

Here is a test case from a recent application security asessment which I have had experienced:

```
cookie = new Cookie(strKey1, EncryptDecrypt.encrypt(strValue));
cookie.setMaxAge(-1); 
cookie.setDomain(COOKIE_NEW_DOMAIN);
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setSecure(true); // for secure cookie by java
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Although 'setSecure' is set to true, does this prevent attacks against attacks on the application via XSRF/CSRF/See-Surf or XSS/CSS or HTTPOnly has to be on HTTP headers!? or both?

Comment: did you look up to see what setSecure did?

Comment: It was set by the coder commenting it out and describing it was implemented for java secure cookies.

Answer (score 5):

HTTPOnly disallows the cookie from being read by JavaScript via `document.coookie`.

The Secure flag will restrict the cookie to HTTPS, but if your site has an XSS vulnerability, HTTPS will not protect you. The XSS URL `https://example.com?q=<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>` works just as well as `http://example.com?q=<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>`. Only the HTTPOnly flag will disallow script access to the cookie.